# Missing vulkan libraries in lutris

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vulkan, lutris

﻿Message when starting Lutris:
Lutris was unable to detect Vulkan support for the i386 architecture. This will prevent many games and programs from working.
To install it, please use the following guide: https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md

In theory my GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile should be compatible with this version of driver but after trying to install the NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I get this error in the terminal

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libvulkan1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.34) but it is not installable
                       Recommends: mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 but it is not installable or
                                   vulkan-icd:i386
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I see `mesa-vulkan-drivers | 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1   | jammy-updates            | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` available; and `libc6 | 2.35-0ubuntu3.3  | jammy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` available too